# Why are the data I want to extract from a web page not in my soup page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[The web page I am attempting to extract data from.](https://www.questdiagnostics.com/testcenter/TestDetail.action?tabName=OrderingInfo&ntc=36127&searchString=36127)

[Picture of the data I am trying to extract.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bB8Bp.png) I want to extract the Test Code, CPT Code(s), Preferred Specimen(s), Minimum Volume, Transport Container, and Transport Temperature.

When I print the soup page, it does not contain the data I need. Therefore, I cannot extract it. Here is how I print the soup page:

```
soup_page = soup(html_page, "html.parser")
result = soup_page
print(result)
```

But when I inspect the elements of interest from the web page, I can see the HTML contains the data of interest. Here is some of the HTML:

```html
<h4>Test Code</h4><p>36127</p><span class="LegacyOrder" style="word-wrap:break-word;visibility:hidden"></span><input id="primaryTestCode" value="36127" type="hidden"><input id="searchStringValue" value="36127" type="hidden"><span class="LisTranslatableVerbiage" style="word-wrap:break-word;visibility:hidden"></span>
```

Comment: Which laboratory did you select on the website?

Comment: @MartinEvans: I selected the "WA - Seattle 1737 Airport Way S (866)697-8378 (SEA)" laboratory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the website to return the data, you also need to include cookie information which is used to specify the laboratory that you request. In your case `SEA`. This can easily be added as a `requests` parameter as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from operator import itemgetter
import requests

url = 'https://www.questdiagnostics.com/testcenter/TestDetail.action?tabName=OrderingInfo&ntc=36127&searchString=36127'

cookies = {
    "TC11SelectedLabCode" : "SEA",
    "TC11SelectedLabName" : "WA - Seattle 1737 Airport Way S (866)697-8378 (SEA)",
}

r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
data = [el.get_text(strip=True) for el in itemgetter(6, 8, 14, 16, 20, 22)(soup.find_all(['h4', 'p']))]
print(data)
```

This would give you:

```
['36127', '84443', '1 mL serum', '0.7 mL', 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Room temperature']
```

---

You might need to improve the extraction of the information, it assumed the elements returned for each search are consistent. Instead you could search for the required field headings and use the next element, for example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from operator import itemgetter
import requests

req_fields = ["Test Code", "CPT Code(s)", "Preferred Specimen(s)", "Minimum Volume", "Transport Container", "Transport Temperature"]
url = 'https://www.questdiagnostics.com/testcenter/TestDetail.action?tabName=OrderingInfo&ntc=36127&searchString=36127'

cookies = {
    "TC11SelectedLabCode" : "SEA",
    "TC11SelectedLabName" : "WA - Seattle 1737 Airport Way S (866)697-8378 (SEA)",
}

r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
i_fields = (el.get_text(strip=True) for el in soup.find_all(['h4', 'p']))
data = {field : next(i_fields) for field in i_fields if field in req_fields}

print(data)
```

Giving a dictionary containing:

```
{'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s)': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s)': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature': 'Room temperature'}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in order to find the desired page, you must first select the test region from a dropdown menu, and press the button "Go". To do so in Python, you will have to use `selenium`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re, time
def get_page_data(_source):
  headers = ['Test Code', 'CPT Code(s)', 'Preferred Specimen(s)', 'Minimum Volume', 'Transport Container', 'Transport Temperature']
  d1 = list(filter(None, [i.text for i in _source.find('div', {'id':'labDetail'}).find_all(re.compile('h4|p'))]))
  return {d1[i]:d1[i+1] for i in range(len(d1)-1) if d1[i].rstrip() in headers}

d = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')   
d.get('https://www.questdiagnostics.com/testcenter/TestDetail.action?tabName=OrderingInfo&ntc=36127&searchString=36127')
_d = soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser')
_options = [i.text for i in _d.find_all('option', {'value':re.compile('[A-Z]+')})] 
_lab_regions = {}
for _op in _options:
  d.find_element_by_xpath(f"//select[@id='labs']/option[text()='{_op}']").click()
  try:
    d.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='confirm go']").click()
  except:
    d.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='confirm update']").click()
  _lab_regions[_op] = get_page_data(soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser'))
  time.sleep(2)


print(_lab_regions)
```

Output:

```
{'AL - Solstas Birmingham 2732 7th Ave South (866)281-9838 (SKB)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'AZ - Tempe 1255 W Washington St (800)766-6721 (QSO)': {}, 'CA - Quest Diagnostics Infectious Disease, Inc. 33608 Ortega Hwy (800) 445-4032 (FDX)': {}, 'CA - Sacramento 3714 Northgate Blvd (866)697-8378 (MET)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'CA - San Jose 967 Mabury Rd (866)697-8378 (MET)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'CA - San Juan Capistrano 33608 Ortega Hwy (800) 642-4657 (SJC)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'CA - Valencia 27027 Tourney Road (800) 421-7110 (SLI)': {}, 'CA - West Hills 8401 Fallbrook Ave (866)697-8378 (MET)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'CO - Midwest 695 S Broadway (866) 697-8378 (STL)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'CT - Wallingford 3 Sterling Dr (866)697-8378 (NEL)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'FL - Miramar 10200 Commerce Pkwy (866)697-8378 (TMP)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'FL - Tampa 4225 E Fowler Ave (866)697-8378 (TMP)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'GA - Tucker 1777 Montreal Cir (866)697-8378 (SKB)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'IL - Wood Dale 1355 Mittel Blvd (866)697-8378 (WDL)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'IN - Indianapolis 2560 North Shadeland Avenue (317)803-1010 (MJV)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443'}, 'KS - Lenexa 10101 Renner Blvd (866)697-8378 (STL)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'MA - Marlborough 200 Forest Street (866) 697-8378 (NEL)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'MD - East Region - Baltimore, 1901 Sulphur Spring Rd (866) 697-8378) (PHP)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'MD - Baltimore 1901 Sulphur Spring Rd (866)697-8378 (QBA)': {'Test Code': '36127X', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL (0.7 mL minimum) serumPlasma is no longer acceptable', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL'}, 'MI - Troy 1947 Technology Drive (866)697-8378 (WDL)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'MO - Maryland Heights 11636 Administration Dr (866)697-8378 (STL)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'NC - Greensboro 4380 Federal Drive (866)697-8378 (SKB)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'NJ - Teterboro 1 Malcolm Ave (866)697-8378 (QTE)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'NM - Albuquerque 5601 Office Blvd ABQ (866) 697-8378 (DAL)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'NV - Las Vegas 4230 Burnham Ave (866)697-8378 (MET)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'NY - Melville 50 Republic Rd Suite 200 - (516) 677-3800 (QTE)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'OH - Cincinnati 6700 Steger Dr (866)697-8378 (WDL)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'OH - Dayton 2308 Sandridge Dr. (937) 297 - 8305 (DAP)': {'Test Code': '36127'}, 'OK - Oklahoma City 225 NE 97th Street (800)891-2917 (DLO)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': 'PATIENT PREPARATION:SPECIMEN COLLECTION AFTER FLUORESCEIN DYE ANGIOGRAPHY SHOULDBE DELAYED FOR AT LEAST 3 DAYS. FOR PATIENTS ONHEMODIALYSIS, SPECIMEN COLLECTION SHOULD BE DELAYED FOR 2WEEKS. ACCORDING TO THE ASSAY MANUFACTURER SIEMENS:"SAMPLES CONTAINING FLUORESCEIN CAN PRODUCE FALSELYDEPRESSED VALUES WHEN TESTED WITH THE ADVIA CENTAUR TSH3ULTRA ASSAY."1 ML SERUMINSTRUCTIONS:THIS ASSAY SHOULD ONLY BE ORDERED ON PATIENTS 1 YEAR OF AGEOR OLDER. ORDERS ON PATIENTS YOUNGER THAN 1 YEAR WILL HAVEA TSH ONLY PERFORMED.', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 ML', 'Transport Container ': 'SERUM SEPARATOR TUBE (SST)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'ROOM TEMPERATURE'}, 'OR - Portland 6600 SW Hampton Street (800)222-7941 (SEA)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'PA - Erie 1526 Peach St (814)461-2400 (QER)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': 'Preferred Specimen Volume: 1.0 mlSpecimen Type SERUMSpecimen State Room temperaturePatient preparation: Specimen collection after fluoresceindye angiography should be delayed for at least 3 days. Forpatients on hemodialysis, specimen collection should bedelayed for 2 weeks. According to the assay manufacturerSiemens: Samples containing fluorescein can produce falselydepressed values when tested with the ADVIA Centaur TSH3Ultra Assay.STABILITYSerum:Room temperature: 7 daysRefrigerated: 7 daysFrozen: 28 days', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 ml', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator'}, 'PA - Horsham 900 Business Center Dr (866)697-8378 (PHP)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'PA - Pittsburgh 875 Greentree Rd (866)697-8378 (QPT)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'TN - Knoxville, 501 19th St, Trustee Towers – Ste 300 & 301 (866)MY-QUEST (SKB)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'TN - Nashville 525 Mainstream Dr (866)697-8378 (SKB)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'TX - Houston 5850 Rogerdale Road (866)697-8378 (DAL)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'TX - Irving 4770 Regent Blvd (866)697-8378 (DAL)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'VA - Chantilly 14225 Newbrook Dr (703)802-6900 (AMD)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}, 'WA - Seattle 1737 Airport Way S (866)697-8378 (SEA)': {'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}}
```

---

Specifically, for the `"WA - Seattle 1737 Airport Way S (866)697-8378 (SEA)"` laboratory:

```
print(_lab_regions["WA - Seattle 1737 Airport Way S (866)697-8378 (SEA)"])
```

Output:

```
{'Test Code': '36127', 'CPT Code(s) ': '84443', 'Preferred Specimen(s) ': '1 mL serum', 'Minimum Volume ': '0.7 mL', 'Transport Container ': 'Serum Separator Tube (SST®)', 'Transport Temperature ': 'Room temperature'}
```